# WebLogic LDAP Schedulable CRUD Operations

Tags: ldap, oracle-adf, weblogic12c, jdeveloper, bpel

I am working on an application to perform **CRUD** operations on the **LDAP**.

This web application is using the **IdentityStore** class to communicate with the **LDAP**.

Now, some operation, like periodic role switch (from user to user) or deleting users, needs to be **schedulable**.

So my first idea was using a **BPEL** services to connect a **DB** (with which and when to execute the operation) to the **LDAP**.

I know it can done, but I have no clue how does the BPEL works.

**Is there another way?** Keep in mind this project will be deployed on a server with other applications, so it need to be light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used at the end is:

With my little knowledge of the **BPEL** I created some services to which I added
an Java script that uses an internal library I wrote in java (using the **IdentityStore** module), to communicate with the Ldap.

**Note**:
I found that you can use the **LDAP** in the composite, (Right click-> insert -> LDAP), to connect to it. I'd advise you to research that if you want to do this in a 'cleaner' way.